# Continuous Speech Recognition from pocket-sphinx-android-demo

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am trying to get continuous speech recognition working using pocketsphinx. I tried following their tutorial (https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialandroid/), although to me it is somewhat vague and I could not get it to work. I am now trying a different approach: to start with pocket-sphinx-android-demo (https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo) then reduce its limitations (to be able to recognize for longer and more words). I have figured out where the output of the recognition goes, although the demo is still only able to recognize weather words (I removed the digit and phones demos). I have discovered that the activation phrase can have an infinite vocabulary, but I can't figure out what is limiting the vocabulary of the actual recognition. Here is the github link to my project if it may be helpful: https://github.com/Michaelszeng/pocket-sphinx_App_mk2/commits/master

Does anybody know what is limiting the demo recognizer's vocabulary or how I could remove that limitation?